# Is it possible to add a onClick() Event action(in GameObject dropdown) without adding new script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, hololens

I have an MRTK Slate which comes with Pressable Button to close the slate.

When the close button is pressed, the Slate is disabled but not destroyed. This is because in the Events section>Interactable script> GameObject.SetActive() is set by default as shown in fig:

[image: Interactable script selection]

I want to destroy the slate after clicking close button.

I know I can do this by making a script, attaching the slate prefab to the script(or taking the parent of the button till I get slate as parent game object), calling the function, and using `GameObject.Destroy()`.

But I want to understand how the GameObject dropdown in the Interactable script is getting populated :

[image: GameObject dropdown in Event section for Slate]

I understand that the other dropdowns like Transform, Follow me toggle, Solverhandler, etc are displayed because they are attached to the Slate.

But how does the GameObject option is available? This seems a basic thing, but I would like to be sure about how it is coded.

And if it is possible to add my new action in the Gameobject dropdown, if so, how?

I spent time looking at the scripts of Interactable and others, but I am a beginner in C# and was not able to see where is the code which does this.

Any input will help me.

Comment: GameObject & Transform dropdowns are part of the internal Unity scripting. They will be always present since every object in the game scene is a GameObject & every GameObject requires a Transform component.

Comment: Okay, if I understand you correctly, it is not possible for us to edit those scripts as they are internal?

Comment: Yes,  I believe it's not possible.

Comment: What are your needs exactly ? Why do you want to modify the GameObject dropdown ?

Comment: I want to destroy the slate and not simply disable it when the Close button is pressed. I wanted to know if the no. of scripts can be kept to a minimum and destroy the slate by adding the code where the GameObject dropdown seems to come from. Therefore I was wondering if I can edit it within the scripts available from MRTK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't because [`Object.Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) is **static** and in [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html) (which `Interactable.OnClick` uses) via the Inspector you can only select instance methods.

You at lest need a minimal component like

```
public class ObjectDestroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void DestroyObject()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

or if you don't want to do it via the Inspector but automatically

```
public class ObjectDestroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // store the itneractable reference
    [Tootltip("If not provided uses the Interactable on this GameObject")]
    [SerialzieField] private Interactable _interactable;

    // Optionally provide a different target, otherwise destroys the Interactable
    [Tooltip("If not provided destroys the GameObject of the Interactable")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _targetToDestroy;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // use get component as fallback if no Interactable was provided
        if(!_interactable) _interactable = GetComponent<Interactable>();

        // attach the callback on runtime (won't appear in the inspector)
        _interactable.OnClick.AddListener(DestroyObject);
    }

    private void DestroyObject()
    {
        // destroy the object of the interactable if no target was provided
        if(!_targetToDestroy) _targetToDestroy = _interactable.gameObject;

        Destroy(_targetToDestroy);
    }
}
```